# Matching two strings in Python which has Escape character in it(E:()

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Example:

```
temp=PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss
each=PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss
```

I've tried this: `re.match(temp, each)` but it does not match

Comment: Where are your strings?

Comment: temp and each are strings:
temp='PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss'
each='PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss'

Comment: You should putted them between quotation.

Comment: Why use a regex for that? If you need to check if one string starts with another (that is what your re.match is doing), use `each.startswith(temp)`. Or use `re.match(re.escape(temp), each)`. If you need to check if one equals another you need something like `re.match(re.escape(temp) + "$", each)`.

Comment: Yeah they are inside the quotation, but the problem with the escape character().If i remove that this string will results in matching

Comment: So, please check my answer - I think I covered all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

First off, he first argument in `re.match()` is a regex and python will treat them as regex notations, and sine you have parenthesis in `temp` they will be evaluated as capture groups.

You need to escape them if you want a proper match:

```
>>> temp = "PID ie\(\)     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss"
>>> re.match(temp, each)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 46), match='PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss'>
```

Or you could use `re.escape()` in order to escape the regex notations:

```
>>> re.match(re.escape(temp), each)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 46), match='PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss'>
>>>
```

**Secondly** if you just want to check the equality you can simply use `==` operator.

```
temp == each
```

Comment: Please check my comment to the question. It is not clear whether OP wants to check if `each` *starts with* or *is equal* to `temp`. Or even *contains*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep, I see. I just answered the question based on it's description and clarified the miss understandings.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if one string starts with another (that is what your [**`re.match`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is doing, as it only matches at the start of string), use [**`each.startswith(temp)`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith). Or use `re.match(re.escape(temp), each)` since [**`re.escape`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) will automatically escape (add `\`) in front of all "special" characters.

If you need to check if one *starts with* another you do not need a regex:

```
each.startswith(temp)
```

or with a regex:

```
m = re.match(re.escape(temp), each)
```

If you need to check if one *equals* another you need to add the end-of-string anchor:

```
m = re.match("{0}$".format(re.escape(temp)), each)
```

If you need to check if one *contains* another you need to use [**`re.search`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
m = re.search(re.escape(temp), each)
```

or  a non-regex:

```
each.find(temp) > -1
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/yhIWUt):

```
import re
temp="PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss"
each="PID ie()     Invoked      u   5   1n   5n T ss"

# Check if one starts with another
print(each.startswith(temp))
# Same with regex:
print(re.match(re.escape(temp), each))
# Check if one *equals* another
print(re.match("{0}$".format(re.escape(temp)), each))
# Check if one *contains* another 
print(each.find(temp) > -1)
print(re.search(re.escape(temp), each))
```